# why does "HTML file select" changes the order of selected files and sort them alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, select

I am trying to get the name of the files that are selected by a "file" input in HTML:

```
<input type="file" class="filestyle" name="file-select[]" id="file-select" accept="image/*" multiple>
```

I wrote this JavaScript code to do that:

```
$('#file-select').on("change", function(){
    var selectedFiless = this.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedFiless.length; ++i) {
        var name = selectedFiless.item(i).name;
        alert(name);
    }
});
```

However, I noticed that the names are sorted in alphabetical order, not in selection order. for example, if I select z.jpg and then a.jpg, when I print the names, I have a.jpg, z.jpg (alphabetical order). but I want z.jpg, a.jpg (selection order).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll appear based on how you have `sorted` in your system. I mean if you have set **Sort by** ascending in your system then irrespective or order you select, it will be selected in ascending order and vice versa for descending. I have tested in your `code` and the results are as I have mentioned above.

A **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/orj8516r/)** to test in your local systems.

Answer (score 2):

[`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) does not indicate any specific order of indexes corresponding to user selected files