# HTML : How to sort files by user seleted

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sort files as the user selected.

> When I seelect a image named 3,2,1 and click the button "Click me", it
>   will show 1,2,3 in console.log()

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="tmpFiles" name="img[]" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
 
</body>
</html>

<script>
    
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("tmpFiles").files
        console.log(x)
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: Can this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857936/why-does-html-file-select-changes-the-order-of-selected-files-and-sort-them-al

Answer (score 0):

try this. this should be work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#tmpFiles').on("change", function(){
            var selectedFiless = this.files;
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedFiless.length; ++i) {
                var name = selectedFiless.item(i).name;
                alert(name);
            }
        }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <input id="tmpFiles" name="img[]" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
  
 
</body>
</html>
```